# How to bind collection to WPF:DataGridComboBoxColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a simple object like:

```
class Item
{
  ....

  public String Measure { get; set; }
  public String[] Measures {get; }
}
```

Which I am trying to bind to a DataGrid with two text columns and a combo box column.
For the combo box column, property Measure is the current selection and Measures the possible values.

My XAML is:

```
<DataGrid Name="recipeGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          CellEditEnding="recipeGrid_CellEditEnding" CanUserAddRows="False"
          CanUserDeleteRows="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Food" Width="Auto"
                            Binding="{Binding Food.Name}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity" IsReadOnly="False"
                            Binding="{Binding Quantity}" />

        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Measure" Width="Auto"
                                SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Path=Measure}"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Measures}" />

    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The text column are displayed just fine but the combobox is not - the values are not displayed at all. The binding error is:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=Measures; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridComboBoxColumn' (HashCode=11497055); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in that Columns does no inherit DataContext.

See more here [Binding in a WPF data grid text column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502389/binding-in-a-wpf-data-grid-text-column)

here [blogs.msdn.com/vinsibal/archive/2008/12/17/wpf-datagrid-dynamically-updating-datagridcomboboxcolumn.aspx](http://blogs.msdn.com/vinsibal/archive/2008/12/17/wpf-datagrid-dynamically-updating-datagridcomboboxcolumn.aspx)

and here http://blogs.msdn.com/jaimer/archive/2008/11/22/forwarding-the-datagrid-s-datacontext-to-its-columns.aspx

Comment: Well, if that is true then why do the text columns work but the combo box column doesn't??

Comment: If I understand it correctly it is because the text columns are bound directly  to a property in the DataGrid's ItemsSource,

DataGrid.ItemsSource->Item->Measure

 and the ComboBox are implicitly bound to DataContext of the Item, which is not inherited. 

DataGrid.ItemsSource->Item->DataContext->Measures/Measure

This is how I understood it, admittedly I see now that I am not very good at explaining it. Possibly someone can do it better than me.

Comment: > Note that the reason Binding does work is because the internal code dynamically sets the binding of DataGridColumn.Binding to the DataGridCell.Content (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/archive/2009/04/07/5-random-gotchas-with-the-wpf-datagrid.aspx)

Answer (score 23):

This is hands down the best solution:

http://wpfthoughts.blogspot.com/2015/04/cannot-find-governing-frameworkelement.html

The idea here is that you declare a **CollectionViewSource** as a static resource and then declaratively bind it to ItemsSource of the **DataGridComboBoxColumn**.

Create and bind a static CollectionViewSource:

```
 <Page.Resources>
     <CollectionViewSource x:Key="Owners" Source="{Binding Owners}"/>
 </Page.Resources>
```

And then bind your target ItemsSource:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Owners}}"
```

Comment: Simple and effective!  You can also put the `CollectionViewSource` directly in `<DataGrid.Resources>` if it's not used elsewhere.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but how does this work when the ObservableCollection lives in the ViewModel and not the View?

Answer (score 2):

If your measures are common for all objects, then you can make measures static

```
public String[] Measures { get; }
```

And your xaml will use it as it's shown below:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn
    Header="Role"
    SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Role}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static local:ProjectsDataContext.Roles}}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
```

Hopefully, it will help.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to bind to the data context item for the row to a combobox, you can use a `DataGridTemplateColumn` with a `ComboBox` in its template instead. Note that you have to add the `Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` properties to the `SelectedItem` binding or it will not update properly.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="My Stuff">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyThings}"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedThing, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```