# DataGridComboBoxColumn binding to List<Enum>

Tags: wpf, list, binding, enumeration, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I want to bind a list of enum values to a 'DataGridComboBoxColumn'.
I've tried a lot, but nothing really works.

Here is what I have:

viewmodel-class:

```
public class ViewModel
    {

        public ViewModel()
        {
            TestCollection= new ObservableCollection<MyEnum>();
            AnyClasses = new ObservableCollection<AnyClass>();

            //... fill AnyClasses with stuff...

            TestCollection.Add(MyEnum.Value1);
            TestCollection.Add(MyEnum.Value2);
            TestCollection.Add(MyEnum.Value3);
            TestCollection.Add(MyEnum.Value4);
            TestCollection.Add(MyEnum.Value5);

        }

        public ObservableCollection<MyEnum> TestCollection { get; set; }
       public ObservableCollection<AnyClass> AnyClasses { get; private set; }

}
```

my enum:

```
public enum MyEnum
    {
        Value1,
        Value2,
        Value3,
        Value4,
        Value5
    }
```

Codebehind:

```
 public partial class WPFWindow
    {
        private ViewModel Vm { get; set; }

        public WPFWindow() 
        { 
            InitializeComponent(); 
            Vm = new ViewModel(); 
            DataContext = Vm; 
        }
...
    }
```

and finally the XAML:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="289" x:Name="dataGridAnything" ItemsSource="{Binding AnyClasses}" >
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn Width="200" Header="Optionen" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=Window}, Path=DataContext.TestCollection}" SelectedValuePath="Value"/>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

If I start the project, nothing is displayed in the DataGridComboBoxColumn. What did I do wrong? Thx for you help.

Edit: you can download the project (built with VS 2013) here: 
[Download](http://www.file-upload.net/download-8896616/BindListOfEnumVS2013.zip.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ObjectDataProvider` as mentioned in [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcomboboxcolumn%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It's the preferred way of binding enum to combo boxes since you don't have to manually fill enum collection in your code.

Declare `ObjectDataProvider` in your resources:

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="myEnum" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type core:Enum}">
    <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        <x:Type Type="{x:Type l:MyEnum}"/>
    </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>
```

(You have to declare your local namespace `l` and `core` namespace: `xmlns:core="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"`)

then bind `DataGridComboBoxColumn` to it:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Width="200" Header="Optionen" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myEnum}}" SelectedValuePath="Value"/>
```

**EDIT**

Since you have to modify your enum collection in runtime, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16303114/binding-datagridcomboboxcolumn)

In short, it's a known issue of `DataGridComboBoxColumn`. You have to alter its element style:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Width="200" Header="Optionen">
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="ComboBox.ItemsSource" 
                                    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, 
                                Path=DataContext.TestCollection}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="ComboBox.ItemsSource" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}, 
                                Path=DataContext.TestCollection}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Comment: Well - that works if you can use an enumeration without a list. But the reason why I use a list is: if one item is choosen, it should not be displayed in the other comboboxes. To do that, I remove an item out of the list, if it was set.

Comment: Thank you - that worked. 
Unfortunately now I see what I totally forgot when I started: if I remove one item out of the collection, it will not be selectable for the other "cells". BUT: it is also not selectable for the current cell - of course. Well - my fault.