# Binding Converter for DataGridComboBoxColumn.TextProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I'm trying to use a binding converter to convert Enums displayed in a DataGridComboBoxColumn to a more friendly form. But i'm getting this error; Value '' cannot be converted. I'm applying the binding in the code.

```
 void ResultGrid_AutoGeneratingColumns(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
        {

            if(e.PropertyType.IsEnum)
          {
              var EnumColumn = e.Column as DataGridComboBoxColumn;
              EnumColumn.TextBinding = (new Binding(e.PropertyName) { Converter = new EnumConverter() }) ;
           }

        }
```

And here's my converter

```
 public class EnumConverter : IValueConverter
        {
            public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                String name = Enum.GetName(value.GetType(), value).Replace('_', ' ');
                return name;
            }

            public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
```

[image]

This is the enum im trying to bind

```
 public enum TransactionTypes : int
    {
        Manual_Transaction = 1,
        SubSystem_Transaction = 2
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [DataGridComboBoxColumn binding to List<Enum>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23535159/datagridcomboboxcolumn-binding-to-listenum)

Comment: @Greg The enum binding works fine. What im asking is why the binding converter doesn't work.

Comment: Where and when are you getting this error?

Comment: The error is thrown from the binding engine; Check the edit above

Comment: What about the `Source` of the `Binding`? Also the `TextBinding` seems to be able to change the text of the selected item only, when dropping down, user can still see the ugly/unfriendly text of the Enum values shown (with underscores).

Comment: The itemsource of the datagrid is an ObservableCollection of 'Transaction' Objects each Of these has a 'TransactionType'. As you see in the image I posted the binding is working fine but the error comes when the converter is applied.

Comment: Is it possible that the enum is being assigned the value 0 (at startup) which does not have a string and therefore can not be converted?

Comment: You can turn on debug info output for the WPF Binding Engine and see what it doesn't like there, alternatively the WPF Utility 'Snoop' also lets you see more detailed binding errors.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409960.aspx, @o_weisman also has a decent idea.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the value in the column is not Enum.

I would suggest to use following code:

```
public class EnumConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo    
    {
       String name = value.ToString().Replace('_', ' ');
       return name;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

If value is not enum you have opportunity to see what is inside.

Comment: No i'm sure it's an enum. I've stepped through the Converter Code and I'm sure the Converter works.

Comment: Hmmm... Please check if valie is not null.

Comment: Yes im certain its not null. Infact it returns the strings formatted perfectly as expected. But the binding fails