Binding in DataGridComboBoxColumn does not work
Why does it work this way :
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Format"
         SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Format, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource with formatenumvalues}}"
IsReadOnly="False"/>

That's how it works too :
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Category">
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding CategoryList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding Category, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>

But not like this :
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Category"
         SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Category, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         ItemsSource="{Binding CategoryList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         IsReadOnly="False"/>

Can DataGridComboBoxColumn only work with static resources or is there something else wrong?
categoryList here is ObservableCollection, Category is a regular string.
I have tried various binding options provided by neural networks. I also tried to find a similar solution, but none of them helped.

Are the "Category" and the "CategoryList" on the same class? I would assume that the "CategoryList" is not repeated on every item in the DataGrid ItemsSource.  Can you check for binding errors?

@Gilad Waisel  The CategoryList is ObservableCollection and the Category is string. Visual Studio does not issue any errors regarding these bindings. I also noticed that although ComboBox changes the value of Category, it does not display what is currently selected there when loading the window. Are identical strings considered different objects?

It seems that using the DataGridTemplateColumn is the solution. You can reference previous question :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890156/how-to-bind-collection-to-wpfdatagridcomboboxcolumn

The following code is working:
<DataGridComboBoxColumn    SelectedValueBinding="{Binding Category, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding CategoryList}"/>
                            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding CategoryList}"/>
                            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn>

The "Category" and the "CategoryList" are properties on the item class.

Thank you very much.  You've been very helpful. This is exactly the solution I was looking for.
