# WPF Datagrid - Set Column visibility per row

Tags: wpf, datagrid

Is there any way to hide a given column based on a binding.  I've tried setting the visibility property on DataGridTextColumn (using the correct converter), but that doesn't seem to work.  If I set the value directly (not through binding) it works.  So is column visibility an all or nothing deal with the datagrid?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All you really have to do is add:

```
    <Style x:Key="vStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding YourObjectVisibilityProperty}"/>
    </Style>
```

and then in use the following in your columns:

```
<DataGridTextColumn CellStyle="{StaticResource vStyle}"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this post, the problem is explained
[Binding in a WPF data grid text column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502389/binding-in-a-wpf-data-grid-text-column)
and here
[http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2008/11/22/forwarding-the-datagrid-s-datacontext-to-its-columns.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20160227001645/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/jaimer/archive/2008/11/22/forwarding-the-datagrid-s-datacontext-to-its-columns.aspx)

Quoting JaredPar from the first link
"Essentially the problem is that the DataGridTextColumn has no parent from which to inherit a Binding because it is not a part of the logical or visual tree. You must setup an inheritance context in order to get access to the binding information"

Workaround in order to get this to work..

```
public class DataGridContextHelper
{
    static DataGridContextHelper()
    {
        DependencyProperty dp = FrameworkElement.DataContextProperty.AddOwner(typeof(DataGridColumn));
        FrameworkElement.DataContextProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(DataGrid),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata
           (null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits,
           new PropertyChangedCallback(OnDataContextChanged)));
    }

    public static void OnDataContextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid grid = d as DataGrid;
        if (grid != null)
        {
            foreach (DataGridColumn col in grid.Columns)
            {
                col.SetValue(FrameworkElement.DataContextProperty, e.NewValue);
            }
        }
    }
}

public partial class App : Application
{
    static DataGridContextHelper dc = new DataGridContextHelper(); 
}

<DataGrid x:Name="c_dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=SelectedItem}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Visibility="{Binding Path=(FrameworkElement.DataContext), RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Converter={StaticResource HideColumnAConverter}}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

object IValueConverter.Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        return Visibility.Visible;
    }
    // Whatever you're binding against
    TestClass testClass = value as TestClass;
    return testClass.ColumnAVisibility;
}
```

Comment: That works for the entire column...what I'm looking for is individual row control.  For example, row 1 has 5 columns and row 2 has 4 columns because one of them is hidden.

Comment: Updated my example, hopefully this will do it :) Added DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=SelectedItem}" for the DataGrid and a Converter for each column.

Comment: Or maybe a better way to do it without the converter if you're binding against a Visibility Property. <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value}" Visibility="{Binding Path=(FrameworkElement.DataContext).ColumnAVisibility, RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}" />

Comment: I'll give you credit since you got me thinking, but in the end there seems to be a much easier solution.

Comment: Then please share this easier solution with us, AKoran ;)