# WPF trigger on datagrid to hide/show columns according to bindings

Tags: wpf, binding, wpfdatagrid

I have a data grid like this:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserDeleteRows="True"
          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Margin="10,10,10,10" 
          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
          CanUserAddRows="False" ItemsSource="{Binding ListGestores}"
          ToolTip="Selecione uma linha e pressione DELETE para remover uma unidade.">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding TB_UNIDADE.DS_NOME_UNIDADE}" CanUserResize="False" Header="Setor" IsReadOnly="True" x:Name=""/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding TB_UNIDADE.TB_UNIDADE2.DS_NOME_UNIDADE}" CanUserResize="False" Header="Unidade" IsReadOnly="True" x:Name=""/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding TB_CONTATOS.DS_NOME}" CanUserResize="False" Header="Gestor" IsReadOnly="True" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The problem is that i need to verify if the 2 column binding is null, and if it is null, i need to Hide it, and Change the Header of the column 1.

I know that i can do that with Triggers, but how exactly???
I started with:

```
<DataGrid.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TB_UNIDADE.TB_UNIDADE2}" Value="{x:Null}">
        <Setter Property="" Value="" />
    </DataTrigger>
</DataGrid.Triggers>
```

But i don't know what setter or whatever to put !

Help me =]

Comment: Ok - so you want to hide a column if there is no data in it - in all the rows or what? @decyclone: Your proposed solution assumes that the small object is in the datacontext of the datagrid itself - I think that would work if one uses a relativebinding to traverse upwards, but I am not sure if it is what the question is about. If it is when all rows with that column is empty I would use a (relativesource) binding on visibility to datagrid.Itemssource with a valueconverter that runs through all the items - not so lightweight - or I would do it in code when updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Example:

With the following ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public String Data1 { get; set; }
    public String Data2 { get; set; }
    public String Data3 { get; set; }
}
```

You can use following sample XAML:

```
<Grid.Resources>
    <local:DataGridColumnVisibilityConverter x:Key="DataGridColumnVisibilityConverter" />
</Grid.Resources>
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Data1}"
                            Visibility="{Binding, Converter={StaticResource DataGridColumnVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=Data1}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Data2}"
                            Visibility="{Binding, Converter={StaticResource DataGridColumnVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=Data2}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Data3}"
                            Visibility="{Binding, Converter={StaticResource DataGridColumnVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=Data3}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

And converter:

```
public class DataGridColumnVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ViewModel viewModel = (ViewModel)value;

        switch (parameter.ToString().ToLower())
        {
            case "data1":
                return (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(viewModel.Data1)) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
            case "data2":
                return (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(viewModel.Data2)) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
            case "data3":
                return (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(viewModel.Data3)) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        return Visibility.Visible;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't use a Visibility-Binding for a DataGridTextColumn out of the box, since it isn't in the visualtree and doesn't have a DataContext.

Comment: actually, you can, It works like a charm. +1 for decyclone. Alternatively, you can make your own DataGridTemplateColumns and use DataTriggers, but here it is easier to use decyclone's solution I think.

Comment: @David: I've never gotten that to work without using an inherited datacontext (discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502389/binding-in-a-wpf-data-grid-text-column). I tried this example and all I got was "System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:(no path); DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridTextColumn' (HashCode=39268741); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')"

Comment: @David: Yes, it works by setting the values like that. What doesn't work is the Binding. Meaning: this works: <DataGridTextColumn Visibility="Hidden" />. However, this don't: <DataGridTextColumn Visibility="{Binding MyVisibilityProperty}" />

Comment: Understood that shortly after writing my comment, so I deleted it, but too late ;)