# WPF DataGridColumn foreground color turn red if value is negative

Tags: c#, wpf

I want the foreground color of a `DataGridColumn` to change based on its value. I have

```
<DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Diff1" 
                    Binding="{Binding Change}" Header="Net Chng" 
                    Width="*" IsReadOnly="True"
                    Foreground="{Binding Change,Converter={StaticResource negativeToColor}}">
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

and the converter

```
public class negativeToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LimeGreen);
        double doubleValue = 0.0;
        Double.TryParse(value.ToString(), out doubleValue);

        if (doubleValue < 0)
            brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

        return brush;
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

But the converter shows no effect.

[image]

Comment: put some break point on the Convert method. Be sure the `Change` property supports property change notification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

its because all regular `DataGridColumn` Binding's are relative of the `DataGrid` element, not the Row. in The DataGrid level no property named `Change`, only in row level.

Solution is: using `DataGridTemplateColumn`.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Net Chng" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Change}" Foreground="{Binding Change, Converter={StaticResource negativeToColorConverter}}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

**EDIT:** see [Binding in a WPF data grid text column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/502389/1271037) for more solutions.

Comment: your assumption about the Binding in ***`DataGridBoundColumn`*** is not correct, at least please explain why this `Binding="{Binding Change}"` works but `Foreground="{Binding Change...` does not. With your assumption, the `Binding="{Binding Change}"` of course ***should not*** work.

Comment: @KingKing The purpose of `Binding` Property  relates to cell level, not at the Column. Therefore, the `DataGridTextColumn` class do not use it directly, but applies the binding-expression of his to the each auto-generated TextBox per row. However the rest of the properties, you do not expect, for example, the `Header` property suck his Context from each cell separately.
Sorry for English if it is garbled, and thanks for challenging it.

Answer (score 1):

foreground color of a DataGridColumn to change based on its value if value is negative then color is red other black
xmal code is`

```
<Local:AlphabetTextColumn 
                        Header="  Contribution %"
                         x:Name="SalesaAmount2"
                        Binding="{Binding salesContribution}"                        
                        >

                    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding ColorSet}" />                         
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                </Local:AlphabetTextColumn>`
```

code in viewmodel is

```
 if(model.salesContribution<0)
{
model.ColorSet="Red";
}
else
{
model.ColorSet="Black";
}
```

add colorset variable is model

```
public string  ColorSet { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent hours for seeking the error why the converter didn't work. The cause was that I used the wrong `Brushes`:

```
System.Drawing.Brushes.Red;
```

instead of

```
System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red;
```